# Como instalar java 8 32bits no Linux Deepin x86_64

Tags: linux

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8
```

instala java 64bits, alguém sabe como forçar a instalação do java 32bits?

Comment: `sudo apt install oracle-java8:i386`

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: E: Impossível encontrar o pacote oracle-java8:i368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe o java [aqui](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html);

Duplo click no pacote e coloque-o em /tmp ou
   vá para o shell e...

```
$ tar xvzf ~/Downloads/jdk-8*.tar.gz -C /tmp/
```

Na linha de comando, crie um diretorio, se não existir e atribua o root como owner, atribua permissões de execução e mova para `/usr/lib/jvm/`

```
$ sudo su
$ if [ ! -d "/usr/lib/jvm" ]; then mkdir /usr/lib/jvm; fi
$ chown -R root:root /tmp/jdk1.8*
$ chmod -R +x /tmp/jdk1.8*/bin
$ mv /tmp/jdk1.8* /usr/lib/jvm/
```

Instale-o

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/java 1065    

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/javac 1065

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/jar 1065

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/javaws 1065
```

Check ou Set a versão do java que vc tem/quer usar:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Configure a variável ambientaç (opcional), editando o arquivo `$HOME/.bashrc` acrescentando a linha:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8[uX]
```

[uX] no final do comando acima equivale aos digitos finais da versão q vc instalou.

Finalmente, teste a instalação:

```
java -version
```

Comment: Mas aí não será instalado o x86_64?

Comment: Qual vc baixou?